# How to visualize 3D time evolution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

To visualize a 4D function:

```
f(x,y,z,t)
```

I used the following code to observe a z-slice at z=z0:

```
for i = 1:t
    imagesc(squeeze(f(:,:,z0,i))
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Is there a way to directly visualize the entire 3D picture of this time evolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
for i = 1:t
    % plot f(:,:,:,i)
    pause(0.1)
end
```

then you need to choose how you want to visualize your 3D data. For instance, taken from [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html):

```
for i = 1:t
    p = patch(isosurface(f(:,:,:,i), 42)); % Where 42 is the isovalue
    isonormals(f(:,:,:,i), p)
    set(p, 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    daspect([1,1,1])
    view(3); axis tight
    camlight; lighting gouraud
    pause(0.1)
end
```

NB: You can also replace `pause(0.1)` by `drawnow` which pauses just long enough for the plot to refresh.

Comment: btw, do you know what exactly does the 'isovalue' define? there seems to be a default value if I leave isovalue undefined.

Comment: `isosurface` plots a surface corresponding to all the points (x,y,z) satisfying f(x,y,z) = λ where λ is a constant (which I called isovalue above).

Answer (score 1):

Use plot3, scatter3, mesh, or surf.

If you have a newer matlab version, in the command window, open the workspace, select the 3 variables you want and click the plots tab. The available plots will then be suggested along the top.